# Is there a way that I can have functionality like if-else in where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following table structure. On the basis what type of request comes, I should be able to pick the right column for matching the value.

```
| resource_id | result | request          | 
|             | 15127  | /campaign/add    |
|  15127      |        | /campaign/modify |
```

For eg:

if the request is like `/campaign/add` then result should be compared with the number the is sent by the user else resource_id should be picked.

Programmatically I can say

```
if(request.equals())
     fetch values from database where resource_id = 15127
else
     fetch values from database where resource_id = 15127
```

Now I need to do same thing using database.

Comment: case... when... then... else... end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to do that:

```
select *
from the_table
where case 
        when request = '/campaign/add' then result
        when request = '/campaign/modify' then resource_id 
      end = number_sent_by_the_user
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
where (request like '/campaign/add%' and result = $user_Input) or
      (request like '/campaign/modify%' and resource_id = $user_Input)
```